# The value in the string array is overwritten and not completely replaced

Tags: c++, arrays, console-application

When I execute the "consoleinfo()" function twice with the first text longer than the second, the value in the array overlaps the first

This is my code:

```
string last[20];

void consoleinfo(string log)
{
    arrayshift();
    last[18] = "[INFO] " + log;
    consolerefresh();
}
```

Shift all values:

```
void arrayshift()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < (sizeof(last) / sizeof(last[0])); i++)
    {
        last[i - 1] = last[i];
    }
}
```

Print all values of last:

```
void consolerefresh()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(last) / sizeof(last[0])); i++)
    {
        std::cout << last[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My input:

```
consoleinfo("Hello World!");
consoleinfo("Apple");
```

Output:

```
[INFO] Hello World!
[INFO] Apple World!
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre]. Have you omitted code that moves the output location in the console window?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO here is a typo `last[18] = "[INFO] " + log;`, must be `last[19] = "[INFO] " + log;`.

When you type the first time, you get in the console

> [INFO] Hello World!

When you type the second time, the last line is output in the same place where the previous last line was output, the word Hello is rewritten with the word Apple.

> **[INFO] Apple** World!

You have to clean the console before output or fill the last text with spaces till the console width or till the previous line width. It would be obvious if you used longer or shorter word than Hello.

```
last[18] = "[INFO] " + log;
if (last[17].length() > last[18].length())
  last[18] += std::string(last[17].length() - last[18].length(), ' ');
```